# Expedia Api and ASP.Net ( 403 Developer Inactive)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, api

I'm new to Webservices and to ASP.Net..

I'm trying to retrieve the hotel in a certain city.. I used add service reference..

1. it didn't accept the XML schema (`http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3?_wadl&type=xml&apiKey=[xxxYourAPIkeyxxx]`)
   It accepted the Soap WSDL (`http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3?_wadl&type=xml&apiKey=[xxxYourAPIkeyxxx]`)
2. After that I could access the classes but I have no Idea how can i return the list or provoke he method I tried to create a form and I've set the action to http://api.ean.com/ean-services/ws/hotel/v3/ as mentioned in the documentation

> ```
> <form runat="server" action="http://api.ean.com/ean-services/ws/hotel/v3/">
> <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Unnamed1_Click"/>
> </form>
> ```

this returns an XML with error 403 developer Inactive

I have added my IP address to the application in the EAN website

Please I need any help you can give me whether in tutorials , examples or some explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding a service reference I created a form and a button in my defualt.aspx

> ```
> <form runat="server">
> <asp:Button ID="button3" runat="server" OnClick="button3_Click" />
> </form>
> ```

the button invokes the method button3_Click in the defualt.aspx.cs (ExpediaAPIShared is the name I gave the service when I added it)

> ```
>   ExpediaAPIShared.HotelServicesClient client = new HotelServicesClient();
>   ExpediaAPIShared.HotelListRequest hotelListRequest = new HotelListRequest();
>   ExpediaAPIShared.HotelList hotelList = new HotelList();
>   ExpediaAPIShared.HotelListResponse hotelListResponse = new HotelListResponse();
>   client.Open();
>   hotelListRequest.apiKey = "6ppdh333hagfauy5724hdggn";//use ur own key
>   hotelListRequest.cid = 55505; //this is the CID for testing
>   hotelListRequest.city = "Riyadh";
>   hotelListRequest.datelessSupplierSort = true;
>   hotelListResponse = client.getList(hotelListRequest);
>   hotelList = hotelListResponse.HotelList; 
>     for (int i = 0; i < hotelList.size; i++)
>     {
>         Response.Write(hotelList.HotelSummary[i].name);
>         Response.Write("</br>");
>    }
> ```

I needed to initiate each type because if i didn't the value of the object will remain null and I won't be able to add any value to it's attribute.

This code will return only the names of hotels in Riyadh..

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer your question without seeing the API documentation. It seems from your question that the Expedia API supports two ways of accessing it. One is through a SOAP call (where you do an Add Service Reference to a WSDL file), and one is through a form POST. You should use one or the other. Add Service Reference is probably easiest. Just look at the files that Add Svc Ref generated, there should be a class there whose name ends with "...Client". Just create an instance of that class, and it will have the methods for your service. There's a tutorial at http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/consuming-data-wcf-service.html

Comment: Thank you so much you have helped me by pointing to the client class... I'm posting my code as the answer..