# How to use EAN web service in vs2010 web application

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am new to asp.net development for EAN. Does anyone can step me through what should I do after getting the EAN key. I could not find any .NET developer guide from their site. I use other api like youtube, google but EAN is really new to me.

So I have created 1 new website using VS2010 backend C#. Just a simple page with a city, check in, check out form.

Now what should I do ? I see from the following forum that I now have to add a web service reference. But how ?

[Expedia Api and ASP.Net ( 403 Developer Inactive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840796/expedia-api-and-asp-net-403-developer-inactive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if what you're asking exactly

you can see [How to: Add a Reference to a Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx)

if you mean how can you add the WSDL file to your application you can do so by right-clicking on your project and choosing either "add web reference" or "add service reference"  see for more details

[2. Create the Client Program](http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2010/09/create-simple-web-service-in-visual.html)

after you set up your WSDL you can do something similar to the accepted answer on

[Expedia Api and ASP.Net ( 403 Developer Inactive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840796/expedia-api-and-asp-net-403-developer-inactive)